# How can I connect to Postgres database in the container via port 5432

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile

I am running a postgres docker container by using the commands below: (reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/)

`docker build -t eg_postgresql .`

`docker run --rm -P --name pg_test eg_postgresql`

This works but the port number is dynamic. I can connect to the database by giving the port number. (the port I see in docker ps command)
I would like to connect to this docker database from Python so I need a static port number.

I tried the parameters below:

`-p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432`

`-p 5432:5432`

In that case, the docker container's port number was set as 5432. However, I could not connect to the database. I get `docker user does not exist` error message.
What is your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the Dockerfile from the link you posted. After building the container with

`docker build -t eg_postgresql .`

I started the container with

`docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 --name pg_test eg_postgresql` (which binds localhost port 5432 to the container port 5432)

and then I tried to connect with

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d docker -U docker --password`

It works like a charm. If you get a message that docker user does not exist please double check that all steps from the Dockerfile are executed succesfully during the `docker build` command as the creation of the docker user is done in the command `RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker`. Make also sure that you have no PostgreSQL server running on your localhost so that you can be sure that you are trying to connect to PostgreSQL inside the container.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added some lines to Dockerfile in order to create a new database and tables in it. This causes a problem. I will try to find it out. :)